# Set the resolution of the extended screen in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 with extended screen. One of the screens is set to the resolution of 1600×900 (16:9) and the other is set to 1360×768 (16:9).

I have the latest NVIDIA drivers installed. Can anyone suggest how to increase the screen resolution of other screen too? I'm not getting any option in the list to make it 1600×900 — the limit is 1360×768.

[image]

Comment: What is the native resolution for that screen?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I am not sure how to find the native resolution ,until you can tell me  but both my monitors are same company product and both are alike. So both have same native resolution of  1600 X 900.

Answer (score 3):

You could use xrandr command line tool to set modes

Assuming you have your second monitor connected via VGA it would be like so

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1600x900
```

Now select that mode

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1600x900
```

You may want to check the manual for your setup.

Here is what it would look like if you had two HDMI devices

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1600x900 --left-of HDMI2 --output HDMI2 --mode 1600x900
```

To check what output devices you have you can simply type the following into a terminal

```
xrandr
```

Comment: Yes one monitor is VGA and yes i have tries this way also , anyway i did it again and look up for the screen shot.

Comment: Looks like you need to add the mode for the DVI-I-0 instead of the VGA try `xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --mode 1600x900` and see if that adds the mode.

Comment: X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  32
Its not working dude ... i tried adding 1600x900 for DVI but shows error.